# Struts 1.3.8 Action exectute method not firing, stopped working after no changes

Tags: java, struts-1

For seemingly no reason, my Struts form stopped calling the execute method after a form submit. The url in the browser changes to the url of the save action, but the save action itself never runs. The form data clears, and no redirect happens, no server code in the execute method runs, and the url in the browser changes to the url of the save action. I don't think posting my jsp/javascript/execute method would do much good, because it was working perfectly fine just yesterday and I have confirmed that absolutely nothing has changed since then.

The only part that I think might be useful is the relevant snippets from the struts config.

```
    <action 
        path="/create" 
        type="com.example.presentation.CreateAction"
        name="form"
        validate="false">
        <forward name="successful" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/create.jsp" />       
    </action>

    <action 
        path="/save" 
        type="com.example.presentation.SaveAction"
        name="form"
        scope="request"
        input="/WEB-INF/jsp/create.jsp">
        <forward name="successful" path="/list.do" redirect="true" />       
    </action>
```

Comment: My guess is *something* changed. Either you weren't running the code you thought you were, or something changed. There's nothing here anyone can help so far.

Comment: @DaveNewton A bit more detail about this odd behavior: Last week there was a single domain entry that exhibited this behavior. Literally every other domain entry had zero problems being updated, except for this one. All of its data was valid, and I wrote it off as a strange phenomenon and moved on. Now the create action for this domain is acting the same as that single entry was last week. A friend was testing this morning and discovered that it would sometimes not let her create new entries, and now none are able to be created at all. The Filters are firing though, but no excute method.

Comment: @DaveNewton Source control confirms that nothing has changed since yesterday when it was working fine

Comment: Don't know what filters you're referring to, but ok. Again--there's nothing here that can be used to diagnose anything.

Comment: @DaveNewton I mean Filters that implement javax.servlet.Filter and are defined in web.xml. What can I post that would be helpful?

Comment: Pretty much anything. I mean, you're asking for debugging help on a full request cycle.

Comment: @DaveNewton So...it was silently failing in the validate method of the associated Form class. I never discovered the circumstances that would case it to fail, but my coworker did. Coincidentally I ended up entering the same fail causing data every time while testing before I posted this. I made that validation early on and ended up switching to jquery validate and completely forgot about it....derp. Thanks for your time

Comment: No sweat; stuff like that happens.

Comment: @DaveNewton It definitely does! I appreciate your time.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.